# Copying the selected item full path of project browser

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have EA Element Object now how can we get the full path of the EA Element in the project browser as the menu (copy node path to clipboard) work in EA using addin[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just parse from the element upwards.

```
pck = Repository.GetPackageById(Element.PackageId)
loop while pck.ParentId != 0
  pck = Repository.GetPackageById(pck.ParentId)
```

Just join the package names backwards and you're done.

**Edit** In case you have a child element in focus, you need to recurse `Element.ParentID` until that is zero which is the topmost parent from which you can continue the above loop.

Comment: yes this works if u have element just below package.But if u have element which has child element as shown in the above diagram will it work how EA is accessing it

Comment: See my addition in the answer.